# карусель изображений

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Подскажите, как сделать плавную непрерывную прокрутку изображений

```js
 //Обработка клика на стрелку вправо
$(document).on('click', ".carousel-button-right",function(){ 
 var carusel = $(this).parents('.carousel');
 right_carusel(carusel);
 return false;
});
//Обработка клика на стрелку влево
$(document).on('click',".carousel-button-left",function(){ 
 var carusel = $(this).parents('.carousel');
 left_carusel(carusel);
 return false;
});
function left_carusel(carusel){
   var block_width = $(carusel).find('.carousel-block').outerWidth();
   $(carusel).find(".carousel-items .carousel-block").eq(-1).clone().prependTo($(carusel).find(".carousel-items")); 
   $(carusel).find(".carousel-items").css({"left":"-"+block_width+"px"});
   $(carusel).find(".carousel-items .carousel-block").eq(-1).remove();    
   $(carusel).find(".carousel-items").animate({left: "0px"}, 200); 
   
}
function right_carusel(carusel){
   var block_width = $(carusel).find('.carousel-block').outerWidth();
   $(carusel).find(".carousel-items").animate({left: "-"+ block_width +"px"}, 200, function(){
   $(carusel).find(".carousel-items .carousel-block").eq(0).clone().appendTo($(carusel).find(".carousel-items")); 
      $(carusel).find(".carousel-items .carousel-block").eq(0).remove(); 
      $(carusel).find(".carousel-items").css({"left":"0px"}); 
   }); 
}

$(function() {
//Раскомментируйте строку ниже, чтобы включить автоматическую прокрутку карусели
 auto_right('.carousel:first');
})

// Автоматическая прокрутка
function auto_right(carusel){
 setInterval(function(){
  if (!$(carusel).is('.hover'))
   right_carusel(carusel);
 }, 2000)
}
// Навели курсор на карусель
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.carousel', function(){$(this).addClass('hover')})
//Убрали курсор с карусели
$(document).on('mouseleave', '.carousel', function(){$(this).removeClass('hover')})

</script>
```

```css
.p-smi{
 width: 707px;
    height: 130px;
    margin-left: 358px;
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    margin-top: 69px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px #000000;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 18pt;
    color: black;
    padding: 7px 0 0 0;
}
.carousel  {
     max-width: 1080px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    width: 720px;}
.carousel-wrapper {
  /* margin: 10px 30px;  отступы для стрелок */
   overflow: hidden; /* скрываем содержимое, выходящее за рамки основной области */
   position:relative;
}
.carousel-items {
   width: 10000px; /* устанавливаем большую ширину для набора элементов */
   position: relative; /* позиционируем блок относительно основной области карусели */
}
.carousel-block {
  float: left;
    width: 159px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
}
.carousel-block img{
 display:block;
}

/*********** BUTTONS ***********/
.carousel-button-left a, .carousel-button-right a{
   width: 25px; 
   height: 36px; 
   position: relative;
   top: 80px; 
   cursor: pointer; 
   text-decoration:none;
}
.carousel-button-left a{
   float: left; 
   background: url(../images/carousel-left.png); 
}
.carousel-button-right a{
   float: right;
   background: url(../images/carousel-right.png); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="p-smi">
 <div class="carousel shadow"> 
      <div class="carousel-button-left"><a href="#"></a></div> 
      <div class="carousel-button-right"><a href="#"></a></div> 
  <div class="carousel-wrapper"> 
     <div class="carousel-items"> 
     <div class="carousel-block">
     1
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-block">
     2
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-block">
     3
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-block">
     4
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-block">
     5
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-block">
     6
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-block">
     7
     </div>            
     <div class="carousel-block"> 
     8
     </div>
     </div>
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

А сейчас она не очень? Вроде плавная же!

```js
 //Обработка клика на стрелку вправо
$(document).on('click', ".carousel-button-right",function(){ 
 var carusel = $(this).parents('.carousel');
 right_carusel(carusel);
 return false;
});
//Обработка клика на стрелку влево
$(document).on('click',".carousel-button-left",function(){ 
 var carusel = $(this).parents('.carousel');
 left_carusel(carusel);
 return false;
});
function left_carusel(carusel){
   var block_width = $(carusel).find('.carousel-block').outerWidth();
   $(carusel).find(".carousel-items .carousel-block").eq(-1).clone().prependTo($(carusel).find(".carousel-items")); 
   $(carusel).find(".carousel-items").css({"left":"-"+block_width+"px"});
   $(carusel).find(".carousel-items .carousel-block").eq(-1).remove();    
   $(carusel).find(".carousel-items").animate({left: "0px"}, 500); 
   
}
function right_carusel(carusel){
   var block_width = $(carusel).find('.carousel-block').outerWidth();
   $(carusel).find(".carousel-items").animate({left: "-"+ block_width +"px"}, 500, function(){
   $(carusel).find(".carousel-items .carousel-block").eq(0).clone().appendTo($(carusel).find(".carousel-items")); 
      $(carusel).find(".carousel-items .carousel-block").eq(0).remove(); 
      $(carusel).find(".carousel-items").css({"left":"0px"}); 
   }); 
}

$(function() {
//Раскомментируйте строку ниже, чтобы включить автоматическую прокрутку карусели
 auto_right('.carousel:first');
});

// Автоматическая прокрутка
function auto_right(carusel){
 setInterval(function(){
  if (!$(carusel).is('.hover'))
   right_carusel(carusel);
 }, 2000);
}
// Навели курсор на карусель
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.carousel', function(){
  $(this).addClass('hover')
});

//Убрали курсор с карусели
$(document).on('mouseleave', '.carousel', function(){
  $(this).removeClass('hover')
});
```

```css
.p-smi{
 width: 707px;
    height: 130px;
    margin-left: 358px;
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    margin-top: 69px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px #000000;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 18pt;
    color: black;
    padding: 7px 0 0 0;
}
.carousel  {
     max-width: 1080px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    width: 720px;}
.carousel-wrapper {
  /* margin: 10px 30px;  отступы для стрелок */
   overflow: hidden; /* скрываем содержимое, выходящее за рамки основной области */
   position:relative;
}
.carousel-items {
   width: 10000px; /* устанавливаем большую ширину для набора элементов */
   position: relative; /* позиционируем блок относительно основной области карусели */
}
.carousel-block {
  float: left;
    width: 159px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
}
.carousel-block img{
 display:block;
}

/*********** BUTTONS ***********/
.carousel-button-left a, .carousel-button-right a{
   width: 25px; 
   height: 36px; 
   position: relative;
   top: 80px; 
   cursor: pointer; 
   text-decoration:none;
}
.carousel-button-left a{
   float: left; 
   background: url(../images/carousel-left.png); 
}
.carousel-button-right a{
   float: right;
   background: url(../images/carousel-right.png); 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body> 

<div class="p-smi">
 <div class="carousel shadow"> 
      <div class="carousel-button-left"><a href="#"></a></div> 
      <div class="carousel-button-right"><a href="#"></a></div> 
  <div class="carousel-wrapper"> 
     <div class="carousel-items"> 
     <div class="carousel-block">
     1
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-block">
     2
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-block">
     3
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-block">
     4
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-block">
     5
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-block">
     6
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-block">
     7
     </div>            
     <div class="carousel-block"> 
     8
     </div>
     </div>
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```