# Плавная прокрутка карусели

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Не могу понять как сделать плавную непрерывную прокрутку карусели

```js
 //Обработка клика на стрелку вправо
$(document).on('click', ".carousel-button-right",function(){ 
 var carusel = $(this).parents('.carousel');
 right_carusel(carusel);
 return false;
});
//Обработка клика на стрелку влево
$(document).on('click',".carousel-button-left",function(){ 
 var carusel = $(this).parents('.carousel');
 left_carusel(carusel);
 return false;
});
function left_carusel(carusel){
   var block_width = $(carusel).find('.carousel-block').outerWidth();
   $(carusel).find(".carousel-items .carousel-block").eq(-1).clone().prependTo($(carusel).find(".carousel-items")); 
   $(carusel).find(".carousel-items").css({"left":"-"+block_width+"px"});
   $(carusel).find(".carousel-items .carousel-block").eq(-1).remove();    
   $(carusel).find(".carousel-items").animate({left: "0px"}, 200); 
   
}
function right_carusel(carusel){
   var block_width = $(carusel).find('.carousel-block').outerWidth();
   $(carusel).find(".carousel-items").animate({left: "-"+ block_width +"px"}, 200, function(){
   $(carusel).find(".carousel-items .carousel-block").eq(0).clone().appendTo($(carusel).find(".carousel-items")); 
      $(carusel).find(".carousel-items .carousel-block").eq(0).remove(); 
      $(carusel).find(".carousel-items").css({"left":"0px"}); 
   }); 
}

$(function() {
//Раскомментируйте строку ниже, чтобы включить автоматическую прокрутку карусели
 auto_right('.carousel:first');
})

// Автоматическая прокрутка
function auto_right(carusel){
 setInterval(function(){
  if (!$(carusel).is('.hover'))
   right_carusel(carusel);
 }, 2000)
}
// Навели курсор на карусель
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.carousel', function(){$(this).addClass('hover')})
//Убрали курсор с карусели
$(document).on('mouseleave', '.carousel', function(){$(this).removeClass('hover')})

</script>
```

```css
.p-smi{
 width: 707px;
    height: 130px;
    margin-left: 358px;
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    margin-top: 69px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px #000000;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 18pt;
    color: black;
    padding: 7px 0 0 0;
}
.carousel  {
     max-width: 1080px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    width: 720px;}
.carousel-wrapper {
  /* margin: 10px 30px;  отступы для стрелок */
   overflow: hidden; /* скрываем содержимое, выходящее за рамки основной области */
   position:relative;
}
.carousel-items {
   width: 10000px; /* устанавливаем большую ширину для набора элементов */
   position: relative; /* позиционируем блок относительно основной области карусели */
}
.carousel-block {
  float: left;
    width: 159px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
}
.carousel-block img{
 display:block;
}

/*********** BUTTONS ***********/
.carousel-button-left a, .carousel-button-right a{
   width: 25px; 
   height: 36px; 
   position: relative;
   top: 80px; 
   cursor: pointer; 
   text-decoration:none;
}
.carousel-button-left a{
   float: left; 
   background: url(../images/carousel-left.png); 
}
.carousel-button-right a{
   float: right;
   background: url(../images/carousel-right.png); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="p-smi">
 <div class="carousel shadow"> 
      <div class="carousel-button-left"><a href="#"></a></div> 
      <div class="carousel-button-right"><a href="#"></a></div> 
  <div class="carousel-wrapper"> 
     <div class="carousel-items"> 
     <div class="carousel-block">
     1
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-block">
     2
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-block">
     3
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-block">
     4
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-block">
     5
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-block">
     6
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-block">
     7
     </div>            
     <div class="carousel-block"> 
     8
     </div>
     </div>
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Создание дубля не увеличивает шанс ответа на вопрос.

Comment: Полный дубль вопроса того же автора: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/565170/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9

Comment: Как это не печально, но увеличивает...я не видел дубль, но увидел этот вопрос

Comment: @AlexeyProkopenko, если нужно вопрос поднять, его можно поправить и он всплывет. Или баунти повесить, если репутации хватает.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в функцию *animate* параметр easing='lenear' и поставьте задержку между анимациями равную продолжительности анимации. Тогда прокрутка будет плавной а скорость прокрутки будет задаваться параметром *speed* в функции *animate*

[animate](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_animate.asp)

```js
var duration = 1000

//Обработка клика на стрелку вправо
$(document).on('click', ".carousel-button-right",function(){ 
 var carusel = $(this).parents('.carousel');
 right_carusel(carusel);
 return false;
});
//Обработка клика на стрелку влево
$(document).on('click',".carousel-button-left",function(){ 
 var carusel = $(this).parents('.carousel');
 left_carusel(carusel);
 return false;
});
function left_carusel(carusel){
   var block_width = $(carusel).find('.carousel-block').outerWidth();
   $(carusel).find(".carousel-items .carousel-block").eq(-1).clone().prependTo($(carusel).find(".carousel-items")); 
   $(carusel).find(".carousel-items").css({"left":"-"+block_width+"px"});
   $(carusel).find(".carousel-items .carousel-block").eq(-1).remove();    
   $(carusel).find(".carousel-items").animate({left: "0px"}, 200); 
   
}
function right_carusel(carusel){
   var block_width = $(carusel).find('.carousel-block').outerWidth();
   $(carusel).find(".carousel-items").animate({left: "-"+ block_width +"px"}, duration, 'linear', function(){
   $(carusel).find(".carousel-items .carousel-block").eq(0).clone().appendTo($(carusel).find(".carousel-items")); 
      $(carusel).find(".carousel-items .carousel-block").eq(0).remove(); 
      $(carusel).find(".carousel-items").css({"left":"0px"}); 
   }); 
}

$(function() {
//Раскомментируйте строку ниже, чтобы включить автоматическую прокрутку карусели
 auto_right('.carousel:first');
})

// Автоматическая прокрутка
function auto_right(carusel){
 setInterval(function(){
  if (!$(carusel).is('.hover'))
   right_carusel(carusel);
 }, duration)
}
// Навели курсор на карусель
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.carousel', function(){$(this).addClass('hover')})
//Убрали курсор с карусели
$(document).on('mouseleave', '.carousel', function(){$(this).removeClass('hover')})

</script>
```

```css
.p-smi{
 width: 707px;
    height: 130px;
    margin-left: 358px;
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    margin-top: 69px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px #000000;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 18pt;
    color: black;
    padding: 7px 0 0 0;
}
.carousel  {
     max-width: 1080px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    width: 720px;}
.carousel-wrapper {
  /* margin: 10px 30px;  отступы для стрелок */
   overflow: hidden; /* скрываем содержимое, выходящее за рамки основной области */
   position:relative;
}
.carousel-items {
   width: 10000px; /* устанавливаем большую ширину для набора элементов */
   position: relative; /* позиционируем блок относительно основной области карусели */
}
.carousel-block {
  float: left;
    width: 159px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
}
.carousel-block img{
 display:block;
}

/*********** BUTTONS ***********/
.carousel-button-left a, .carousel-button-right a{
   width: 25px; 
   height: 36px; 
   position: relative;
   top: 80px; 
   cursor: pointer; 
   text-decoration:none;
}
.carousel-button-left a{
   float: left; 
   background: url(../images/carousel-left.png); 
}
.carousel-button-right a{
   float: right;
   background: url(../images/carousel-right.png); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="p-smi">
 <div class="carousel shadow"> 
      <div class="carousel-button-left"><a href="#"></a></div> 
      <div class="carousel-button-right"><a href="#"></a></div> 
  <div class="carousel-wrapper"> 
     <div class="carousel-items"> 
     <div class="carousel-block">
     1
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-block">
     2
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-block">
     3
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-block">
     4
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-block">
     5
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-block">
     6
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-block">
     7
     </div>            
     <div class="carousel-block"> 
     8
     </div>
     </div>
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Интервал без таймаута? Вы даже мне браузер подвесили.

Comment: Действительно, не обратил внимания что это интервал, а не таймаут. Поправил

Comment: все хорошо, только почему-то у меня слева картинка уходит нормально, а крайняя правая когда появляется, то не поялвяется до тех пор, пока не выедит блоr c rfhnbryqj 150px

Comment: понял свою ошибку, всем спасибо большое

Comment: вы решили свою проблему?

Comment: да, спасибо, все решил

Comment: @Aslero, тогда поставьте плюсик человеку который помог ее решить, а еще лучше нажмите галку под рейтингом ответа, чтобы принять ее.