# не понимаю в чем проблема. Вместо перещелкивания блоков, он удаляет их в слайдере карусель

Tags: javascript, slider, carousel

```js
//Обработка клика на стрелку вправо
$(document).on('click', ".work__carousel-button-right", function() {
  var carusel = $(this).parents('.work__carousel');
  right_carusel(carusel);
  return false;
});
//Обработка клика на стрелку влево
$(document).on('click', ".work__carousel-button-left", function() {
  var carusel = $(this).parents('.work__carousel');
  left_carusel(carusel);
  return false;
});

function left_carusel(carusel) {
  var block_width = $(carusel).find('.work__carousel-block').outerWidth();
  $(carusel).find(".work__carousel-items .work__carousel-block").eq(-1).clone().prependTo($(carusel).find("work__carousel-items"));
  $(carusel).find(".work__carousel-items").css({
    "left": "-" + block_width + "px"
  });
  $(carusel).find(".work__carousel-items .work__carousel-block").eq(-1).remove();
  $(carusel).find(".work__carousel-items").animate({
    left: "0px"
  }, 200);

}

function right_carusel(carusel) {
  var block_width = $(carusel).find('.work__carousel-block').outerWidth();
  $(carusel).find(".work__carousel-items").animate({
    left: "-" + block_width + "px"
  }, 200, function() {
    $(carusel).find(".work__carousel-items .work__carousel-block").eq(0).clone().appendTo($(carusel).find(".work__carousel-items"));
    $(carusel).find(".work__carousel-items .work__carousel-block").eq(0).remove();
    $(carusel).find(".work__carousel-items").css({
      "left": "0px"
    });
  });
}

$(function() {
  //Раскомментируйте строку ниже, чтобы включить автоматическую прокрутку карусели
  // auto_right('.work__carousel:first');
})

// Автоматическая прокрутка
function auto_right(carusel) {
  setInterval(function() {
    if (!$(carusel).is('.hover'))
      right_carusel(carusel);
  }, 3000)
}
// Навели курсор на карусель
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.work__carousel', function() {
  $(this).addClass('hover')
})
//Убрали курсор с карусели
$(document).on('mouseleave', '.work__carousel', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('hover')
})
```

```css
work {
  width: 640px;
  height: 380px;
  outline: 1px dashed;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 59PX;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: $font-family;
  &__title {
    margin: 0 40px 40px;
    font-family: $font-family;
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 42px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #4A4A4A;
  }
  &__carousel {
    width: 398px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    position: relative;
    outline: 1px dashed;
    &-wrapper {
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
    }
    &-items {
      //   width: 10000px; 
      height: 200px;
      position: relative;
    }
    &-block {
      width: 398px;
      height: 200px;
    }
    &-href {
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 17px;
      color: #737373;
      text-decoration: none;
      margin-left: 283px;
      position: relative;
      &::after {
        content: url("../img/mini_arrow_right.svg");
        position: absolute;
        top: 1px;
        right: -12px;
      }
    }
    &-button {
      position: absolute;
      width: 620px;
      height: 25px;
      top: 85px;
      right: -101px;
      button {
        position: absolute;
        cursor: pointer;
        list-style: none;
        border: 0;
        outline: 0;
        background-color: inherit;
        &:nth-child(1) {
          left: 51px;
        }
        &:nth-child(2) {
          right: 34px;
          z-index: 10;
        }
        &:nth-child(1):before {
          content: url("../img/btn_case_left-grey.png");
        }
        &:nth-child(2):before {
          content: url("../img/btn_right-grey.png");
          opacity: 0.3;
        }
        &:hover {
          width: 40px;
          height: 200px;
          background-color: #F6F6F6;
          &:nth-child(1):before {
            content: url("../img/btn_left.png");
          }
          &:nth-child(2):before {
            content: url("../img/btn_slider_right.png");
            opacity: 1;
          }
        }
        &:nth-child(1):hover {
          padding-left: 8px;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          padding-top: 9px;
          margin-top: -85px;
          margin-left: -7px;
        }
        &:nth-child(2):hover {
          padding-left: 11px;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          padding-top: 9px;
          margin-top: -85px;
          margin-right: -5px;
        }
      }
    }
    &__text {
      width: 366px;
      height: 154px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding-top: 18px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 22px;
      color: #737373;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="work__carousel">
  <div class="work__carousel-button">

    <button class="work__carousel-button-right"></button>
    <button class="work__carousel-button-left"></button>

  </div>
  <div class="work__carousel-wrapper">
    <div class="work__carousel-items">
      <div class="work__carousel-block">
        <p class="work__carousel__text">Навруз – житель одного из южных регионов России. Ночью на трассе его остановили на блок-посту. Попросили предъявить паспорт, он предъявил свой временный паспорт, которым в то время пользовался После проверки сотрудник органов сказал, что такой
          паспорт по базе непроисходит…</p>
        <a href="" class="work__carousel-href">Читать далее</a>
      </div>
      <div class="work__carousel-block">
        <p class="work__carousel__text">Навруз – житель одного из южных регионов России.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="work__carousel-block">
        <p class="work__slider__text">Навруз – житель одного из южных регионов России. Ночьют…</p>
      </div>
      <div class="work__carousel-block">
        <p class="work__slider__text">Навруз – житель одного из южных регионов России. Ночью на трассе его остановили на бт, которым в т по базе непроисходит…</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вероятно, проблема в [remove](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)? =) Зачем  удалять элементы из DOM, если можно просто прокручивать? А если Вам понадобятся обработчики на блоки? Будете каждый раз детачить/аттачить новые?

Comment: но во всех карсулях так и делают, как мне тогда быть?
вот пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/565170/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9?newreg=2e310beba1e545e0912def6de9fbd8f2